# webpack style, ts and css loader should only build files inside current folder

Tags: webpack

My issue is that I have a webpack project where I include typescript classes / types / css files and resources outside the "src dir" of the project. So basically only files within the "src" folder should be included, no files outside that directory or even higher in file hierarchy.

[image]

These files outside the project dir should not be included in the built, since they are already existing on runtime.
As far as I understood this can achieve by using the resolve function.

```
include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
```

That only results in the error "ReferenceError: path is not defined". I don't know where I would define it actually.

I think this is a rather simple question, but I seem not to find the solution to it.
I am using webpack 4.44.1 and webpack-cli 3.3.12 .

```
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const path = require("path")
module.exports = {
    optimization: {
        minimize: false
    },
    entry: {
        'code': './src/code.ts'
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            cleanAfterEveryBuildPatterns: ['public/build']
        }),
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/public',
        //filename: 'build/[name].[contenthash].js',
        filename: 'build/[name].js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts?$/, use: 'ts-loader', exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|json|xml|ico|cur|ani)$/,
                use: ['file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]']
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [
            '.ts',
            '.js',
            '.json',
        ],
    },
};
```

Comment: It's `require.resolve` or `const path = require('path')` - there's no global called `path` in NodeJS

Comment: this i tried as well, the error will result in Module parse failed: Unexpected token (26:22)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

Comment: however the idea was to make the loader ignore the types and treat them as any instead (same way as vanillaJS would do)

Comment: What is the path of the module that fails / what is the "type" of the file that fails to parse?

Answer (score 2):

You need to import path library before you can use it. Please add this to top of webpack.config.js e.g `const path = require("path")` or if you are using ES6 you can use `import path from "path";`

Comment: thx for the comment, as mentioned above that is unfortunately not working (I did forgot to update the code accordingly - done now)

Comment: @marius what command do you use to run webpack build???